# Nginx with SSL - Refresh page give me 404

Tags: nginx, parse-server

I recently install Nginx for my parse server with SSL support.

Works fine when I type the base https url but when I try to refresh the page I got an 404 error.

Maybe a misconfigured Ngix conf.

Here is my nginx.conf

```
events {
   worker_connections 1024;
}
http{
        server_tokens off;
        charset utf-8;

        # HTTP - redirect all requests to HTTPS
        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        # HTTPS - serve HTML from /usr/share/nginx/html, proxy requests to /parse/
        # through to Parse Server
        server {
                        listen 443 ssl http2;

                        server_name my-app-api.ch ;

                        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                        index index.html index.htm;

                        # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
                        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-app-api.ch/fullchain.pem;
                        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-app-api.ch/privkey.pem;

                        # Pass requests to Parse Server instance at localhost:1337
                        location / {
                                        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
                                        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
                                        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

                                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                                        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
                                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                                        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                                        proxy_pass http://172.20.0.5:1337/;
                                        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                                        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                                        proxy_redirect off;

                                        # enables WS support
                                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                                        proxy_read_timeout 999999999;
        #                                       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                        }
                        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                                root /var/www/certbot;
                        }

                #       location / {
                #               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                #       }
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any idea

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the config. I guess you have to configure your application on `172.20.0.5:1337`

Comment: Thank you for the validation of my config. The problem is that the reverse proxy seems not works for parse server. When I navigate from root path, no problem but when I try to type any mount after, 404 error. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do the acces log say?

Comment: I was so convinced that it came from Nginx that I didn't think it could come from my upstream app.
Sleep on it.
Problem solved.
THANKS